# How to say 'Does it come with...?' like at a restaurant

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, expresiones, méxico, comida

Today I was ordering at the local taqueria and I wanted to ask whether my meal came with chips.  The verbatim translation would use the verb 'venir', something like "viene con chips", but this seems like an abuse of the word venir.  One could ask whether "mi orden incluye chips" but this seems a little too formal.  What would be the best way to ask this, specifically in an informal/casual Mexican dialect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility besides "venir con" and "llevar" is **traer**, not in the sense of bringing but of carrying:

> -¿Trae papas fritas?
>
> -Sí, esta semana el combo trae doble papa gratis.

Comment: Do you have a sense of how common this would be, and/or how clear the subject of the sentence would be?  As in, if I asked this while ordering, it is clear that I'm asking whether my meal "trae papas fritas", or might this be interpreted as "will you bring me chips"?

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese: It's very common. Besides: if you wanted to ask "Will you bring me chips?" you'd have to say: "¿Me trae (usted) papas fritas?" (present... habit) or "¿Me traerá (usted) papas fritas?" (future). That "Me" (or "nos" if there's more than one person at the table) makes a lot of difference. :-)

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese: It has both senses: _el mesero trae las papas_ ("the waiter brings the chips") and _la carne trae papas_ ("the meat comes with chips"). Wences comment clears everything.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese - Actually, I think you raised a good point.  If you are a foreigner, your Spanish may be assumed to be a bit compromised and over-simplified, and someone could indeed interpret "¿Trae papa frita?" as "Are you bringing potato chips / fried potatoes?" which could suggest some impatience and rudeness, and that would not ingratiate you to the waiter.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Con qué viene acompañado?
>
> ¿Con qué viene? *(least formal)*
>
> ¿Cuáles acompañamientos tiene? *(most formal)*

I found these suggestions in http://www.costaricaspanish.net/2010/12/phrases-for-the-restaurant/; they all sound fine to my ear (which is tuned to Mexican Spanish).

Comment: This applies to Colombia too

Answer (score 2):

At least in Argentina and Uruguay you will probably be better understood if you use "venir".

> ¿La carne viene con papas?

Comment: this applies to Colombia too.

Comment: What does this April 3 answer contribute that my April 2 answer did not?  Also, note that the question clearly requests an answer for Mexico, not South America.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I've noticed it because it was used to mark a duplicate.

It specifies Mexican Spanish but this phrase appears in another [answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20330/11102)

> I would say **venir** is grammatically wrong (and idiomatically awkward in any case)

In **Spain** the sentence "¿viene con patatas?" is used commonly, it's totally normal and understandable and **it's NOT grammatically wrong neither idiomatically awkward**.

According to the R.A.E

**[venir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bXkUiz2)**

> 3. intr. Dicho de una persona o de una cosa: Llegar a donde está quien habla.
>      English translation: Applied to person or a thing: **Arrive** where the speaker is.

So if you say "¿esta carne **viene** con patatas?" you are asking "do this meat **come** with fries?" [come and arrive are synonyms in this case, and I think that "come" is more idiomatic in English].

Answer (score 0):

I would just say:

> ¿Lleva patatas/chips?

I would say *venir* is grammatically wrong (and idiomatically awkward in any case), as *ir/venir* (and *llevar/traer*) don't work exactly as in English, and this is one case in which the perspective of the speaker changes.

And I would definitely not use *orden* as a translation of *order*, although I think it's quite common in Mexican Spanish.

Comment: I was quite surprised to discover the usage of _orden_ as a translation of _order_! I had already heard about _carpeta_ for "carpet" and other, I guess the list can just increase with two languages "living" in the same areas.

Comment: According to DRAE: *19. f. Cuba, Méx. y R. Dom. Relación de lo que se va a consumir en una cafetería o restaurante.* In Argentina we use "pedido" for "order" ("orden" is more readily associated with a "purchase order" of some other kind), and we do use "venir": ¿El pedido viene solo o con guarnición? We wouldn't use "llevar". Example: https://www.gurudeofertas.com/oferta/5127/riquisimo-menu-suprema-napolitana-para-2-personas-viene-con-guarnicion-de-ensalada-o-papas-fritas-postre-75

Comment: Aditionally to what @Gustavson said (I'm also argenintinian and agree with all of it) "llevar" would be used if you are talking about the ingredients of a dish: El gulash ¿lleva cebolla? But it's different from the sense of the question because in that case you're not asking if it comes with onions on the side, you're asking if it is made with onions.

Comment: @Gustavson I spent some time in Argentina and definitely used 'venir' in this situation and was understood, but for some reason it never felt quite right.  I guess it was okay there though.

Comment: @Wences That was my understanding of the use of "llevar" as well:  A pizza "lleva un ingrediente" but I wouldn't say my dinner "lleva" chips.

Comment: Patatas?  In Mexico?  Maybe "chips" has been adopted since I left Mexico, but I can't imagine "patatas" would have replaced "papa frita."