# Food questions - 'Is that with...?'

Tags: selección-de-palabras, comida

Let's say I don't want cheese on my food and I want to ask the waiter if something has cheese or not. How do I formulate this question?

I'm particularly confused about the sorting of the words. I came up with 3 ways to ask this;

- ¿Es eso con queso?
- ¿Es que con queso?
- ¿Eso es con queso?

Which would be correct and why?

Comment: Relacionada [How to say 'Does it come with…?' like at a restaurant](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20328/5481)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

¿Eso es con queso? is correct but I think the best way would be to say:

> ¿Eso tiene queso?

In this case it is best to use the verb *"tener"*.

If you are asking for the content of some food and you want to know if it **has** cheese then you use **tiene (tener)**

You would use "ser (es)" if you see something you do not recognize but you think it is cheese. Then you could say:

> ¿Es eso queso? = Is that cheese?

There is an alternative if what you want to know is if something was made **with** cheese. Then you do use **con**

> ¿Eso está hecho **con** queso? = Was that made **with** cheese?

If you are wondering if something comes with cheese on the side then you ask:

> ¿Eso viene con queso? = Does that come with cheese?

I guess that covers most situations, but in any case if it is/comes/has cheese I'd take it :-)

### EDIT

As fedorqui said in the comments there is also:

> ¿Eso lleva queso?

This will translate the same as "does that have cheese?". *Lleva* will also be commonly used when talking about recipes like saying "The recipe asks for cheese"="La receta lleva queso".

Comment: In Spain we also say _¿Eso lleva queso?_

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui I didn't think of that. We use it when talking about the recipe or the food preparation and it is not very common when "talking to the waiter" situation, however it is perfectly understood.

Comment: Yo añadiría además "¿Eso está hecho **cocinado** con queso?". El matiz (que con "queso" puede que no funciona bien) es preguntar por otras necesidades o preferencias: alergias (nueces, marisco, etc.), vegetariano, vegano, kosher... Algo puede no contener carne, pero haber sido cocinado con caldo de pollo, por ejemplo, o no haber sido preparado de acuerdo a algún tipo de necesidad/preferencia religiosa o de otro tipo.

Comment: *¿Eso es con queso?* me parece correcto a mí.

Comment: @pablodf76 Oops! Gracias...corregido.

Comment: @pablodf76 suena un poco forzado. Tal vez sea sintácticamente correcto, pero le falta "azúcar" *it does sound a little bit on the weird side, though, perhaps it is syntactically correct, but lacking a bit of o'l syntactic sugar*

Comment: @hlecuanda No. Es una simplificación de ¿Eso es hecho con queso? donde se omite "hecho". No es la mejor forma pero se entiende.