# The way to ask if some food contains something

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, gramática, selección-de-palabras, comida

I've heard different ways if some food contains something:

> Lleva azúcar?
>
> Tiene azúcar?
>
> Trae azúcar?

What's the difference between them? Can they be used interchangeably?

Also, can "con" be used? If yes, should with be `estar` or `ser`?

> Es con queso?
>
> Está con queso?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that " lleva azúcar?" is the closest to "contiene azúcar?"

When asking "Tiene azúcar?" there is some ambiguity

> Tiene *usted* azúcar? Quisiera poner una poca más en mi café
>
> Tiene *el café* azúcar? Voy a poner un poco si no tiene ya.

You could have the same ambiguity with "trae" and even "lleva", but due to the usage of the language it is stronger in "lleva" than in the other options. "Lleva" or "trae" are perfect options, although "contiene" would be the best. They are all pretty interchangeable, and maybe the only connotation to distinguish between them is what you are talking about (a recipe, a plate, a precook meal...).

Asking about a plate or recipe I would use "lleva" or "tiene". For something manufactured (somethings that comes from a can for example) I would use "tiene" or "contiene".

`Also, can "con" be used? If yes, should with be estar or ser?`

Not really, unless you were asking

> Se hace **con** queso

or

> Viene con queso / patatas fritas?

like asking ["Does it come with ...?"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20328/5481). In the first one you ask if a certain ingredient is used in the process. The second one is "does it come with..."

---

**Note**: It may be also interesting to check the answer in the duplicate question ["Is that with..."?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20828/5481) which also addresses some of the point of your question. Quoting that answer:

> - ¿Eso es **con** queso? is correct but I think the best way would be to say: ¿Eso tiene queso?
> - ¿Eso está hecho **con** queso? = Was that made with cheese?

Comment: en tu ejemplo sobre el azúcar y el café, ¿por qué es correcto "una poca"?

Comment: @Patricio Daría para una pregunta por sí misma. [Azúcar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4gcuzQk) puede ser masculino o femenino. Con artículos determinados, usarías sin duda el masculino (como con "el agua), pero con indeterminados, y en este caso particular que añades "poco/a" después, al no producirse la cacofonía de "...a azúcar", puedes usar el artículo femenino.

Comment: Gracias, me sonaba extraño, pero me parecía muy improbable un error.